# how to add @interval in a line chart ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, intervals

I was trying to add @interval in SSRS for my line chart, so the end user can select day, week, month from @interval. If the end used selects @interval = Week, the line will show only 1 number for every week, so the line will look nicer with less number. 
I am thinking to create @interval in report parameters, then create expression for "chart data-values".
This was the expression I wrote, but it did not work.

```
=switch (Parameters!Interval.Value='Day', sum(Fields!DealPerActiveDealer.Value),
Parameters!Interval.Value='Month', Avg (sum(Fields!DealPerActiveDealer.Value)),
Parameters!Interval.Value='Week', Avg (sum(Fields!DealPerActiveDealer.Value))
```

Does anyone know how to work on this? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I rarely use the Switch but the syntax looks correct. You should be using double quotes instead of single in an expression.

```
=SWITCH(PARAMETERS!INTERVAL.VALUE = "DAY",  SUM(FIELDS!DEALPERACTIVEDEALER.VALUE),
        PARAMETERS!INTERVAL.VALUE = "MONTH",    AVG(SUM(FIELDS!DEALPERACTIVEDEALER.VALUE)),
        PARAMETERS!INTERVAL.VALUE = "WEEK",     AVG(SUM(FIELDS!DEALPERACTIVEDEALER.VALUE))
```

As to your chart, you might also need to change the axis with your time line. I assume it shows every day now but should be dynamic also. Your grouping expression would be something like:

```
=DATEPART(SWITCH(Parameters!Interval.Value = "Day", "d"
            Parameters!Interval.Value = "Month", "m",
            Parameters!Interval.Value = "Week", "ww"), Fields!DATEFIELD.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and let you know the result. Thanks for the help.